# print zip name along with file name

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am using `zipinfo -1 a.zip` command to display contents of zip. How to display zip name every time side by size file name.

**for example there are two zips:**

```
a.zip contains file1, file2, file3, file4
b.zip contains file5, file6, file7, file8
```

**output required:**

```
a.zip file1
a.zip file2
a.zip file3
a.zip file4
b.zip file5
b.zip file6
b.zip file7
b.zip file8
```

Comment: WHat did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
for file in *.zip; do
  bsdtar -tf "$file" | F=$file awk '{print ENVIRON["F"], $0}'
done
```

Here using `bsdtar` instead of `zipinfo` as `zipinfo` doesn't work properly if zip file names contain wildcard characters and its encoding of control characters is ambiguous (for instance, if you see a `^HOME` line, you don't know whether that's `^HOME` literally or `^H` (the representation of the backspace character) followed by `OME`). `bsdtar` uses a `\b` representation and backslash itself is shown as `\\`.

With GNU `grep`, you can prefix lines with `filename:` using `grep -H --label="$file" '^'` instead. See also `perl -nse 'print "$file $_"' -- -file="$file"`. Do **not** use <strike>`sed "s/^/$file /"`</strike> as that's a command injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

For a single zip file something like:

```
unzip -l a.zip | awk 'NR==1{a=$2}; (NR>3 && NF==4){print a, $NF}'
```

should be enough. For convenience when dealing with multiple files you can put the command in a function, replacing a.zip with a variable.